# Difference between 戦争 and 戦火 in this exchange

Tags: meaning

I need some help understanding the difference between 戦争 and 戦火 in this exchange to understand what is meant by 領地にも**戦火**が及びかねない危機に陥る.

To provide some additional context, カノ controls her own territory レフトハンド, and she was currently in someone else's trying to stop a war from starting, but she ended up nearly getting herself killed.

> 「九死に一生を得たとはいえ、死んでいてもおかしくない状況じゃないですか」
>
> 「いやあ、飛び降りたときは心臓が止まるかと思ったよ」
>
> 「笑い事ではありません！！」
>
> 「うう……」
>
> ヒイラギの怒りに気付いたカノは慌てて軽口を止めた。
>
> 「**戦争**を止めるためとはいえ自ら死地に飛び込んだ挙げ句、領地にも**戦火**が及びかねない危機に陥るなど……」
>
> 「レフトハンド家当主の自覚が足りません」

Answer (score 4, accepted):

戦争 is just "war", which is an intangible concept. 戦火 describes something more visible; it refers to individual battles where firearms are used, or fire/destruction caused by them. 戦火 is more or less a "dramatic" word (usually negatively). It is often used in the context where such fire/destruction is treated like a disaster (e.g., あの神社は戦火で失われた, 田畑は戦火で荒らされてしまった).

Comment: I See. Thank you. One more question, as I'm not sure if I am interpreting this correctly or not. Do you understand whether 領地 in this context is referring to  カノ's  領地 or the 領地 where she was?

Comment: @tempytemper 戦火が及びかねない means the 領地 was in danger but was not actually in fire. In addition, it's uncommon to refer to someone else's 領地 without adding ○○の. If カノ returned from a combat zone, this 領地 probably refers to カノ's own 領地.